# Printing a character from a list after a certain character like 'a'

Tags: python, list

I am currently working on a little project for an escape room I'm organizing anyways I'm trying to make a python script read a txt file and store it in a List (this works) however from there I'm trying to make it look trough said list and search for a 1 and make it print the letter that is after the 1 like this where 1H1Ippo would give Hi as a result

I don't have too much knowledge from my classes on how lists work and I've tried this which made sense to me but it gives no result at all which left me clueless to what I could do. I did look on google but couldn't find any results to fix my issue or perhaps I'm just terrible at googling for this issue

```
with open('Wordlist.txt', 'r') as f:
    words = [line.strip() for line in f]

for w in words:
    if w in words == 1:
        print (words[1])
```

Comment: Why do you have backslashes?

Comment: What have you done to actually solve the problem?

Comment: Why would "1H1Ippo" give Hi as a result? Did you mean to say "1H1ippo"? Why is the data structured like this?

Comment: It looks like you need a basic tutorial more than help with a specific problem.

Comment: I have no idea why it was structured like this stack overflow structured it like this and I couldn't find a way to turn it back the way it was aswell as the backslashes were not added by me stackoverflow added those

Comment: @MadPhysicist I think SO changed something in the editor recently. I've been seeing lots of backslashes in code today.

Comment: Actually, your list doesn't contains each world in your file, but each line instead. You should `split` each line and then go through each of them to verify your condition. You can use the `.startswith` method of `str` to check if if starts with `1` and try to access the second element(index 1). You should handle the case where there is no element after your character(length 1).

Comment: @kraken It's common for word lists to be one word per line, so you don't have to split the lines.

Comment: `w in words` will always be true, since `w` is the iteration variable looping over the elements of `words`. So the `if` statement always succeeds. Did you mean `if w == '1':`?

Comment: Due to comparison operator chaining `if w in words == 1` is actually equivalent to `if w in words and words == 1:`. That will never be true.

Comment: `1H1Ippo` looks like a single string, not a list. What does the actual input file look like?

Comment: The file has about 10000 words within it all on a separate line like you stated before @Barmar

Comment: So you want to test `if w[0] == '1':` or `if w.startswith('1')`

Comment: @Barmar I did manage to get it somewhat working with that now I just need to make it look enough times to get it to give the full word I want it to find

Comment: It sounds like you want to concatenate all the `w[1]` when it starts with `1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the first character of `w` is `1`. If it is, accumulate the second character.

```
result = ''
for w in words:
    if w[0] == '1':
        result += w[1]

print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you need

```
with open('Wordlist.txt', 'r') as f:
words = [line.strip() for line in f]

for index, w in enumerate(words):
    if w == '1':
        print(words[index+1])
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're incrementing `index` explicitly instead of using `enumerate(words)`?